# Split src and test files from gulp typescript js stream

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

I am trying to use gulp-typescript to compile my typescript code. I want to send *.spec.js to a folder named "test" and I am trying to send the rest to a folder named "dist". I am trying to [follow this example](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter#restore-as-a-file-source) but instead of my desired result, all of my compiled files end up in "test".

Here is my gulp task file:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var merge2 = require('merge2');    
var config = require('../gulp.config');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var path = require('path');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

var tsproj = ts.createProject(config.files.tsconfig);
gulp.task('typescript:src', function(){
    var testFilter = filter(['src/**/*.spec.ts'], {restore: true, passthrough: false});
    var compileStream = gulp
        .src(['src/**/*.ts', '!src/client/jspm_packages/**'])
        .pipe(ts(tsproj));
        
    var tsd = compileStream
        .dts
        .pipe(concat(path.basename(config.files.srcDefinitions)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.typings));
        
    var js = compileStream
        .js
        .pipe(testFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
        
    var tests = testFilter.restore.pipe(gulp.dest('test'));
        
    return merge2([tsd, js, tests]);
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can archive what you want by doing so:

```
//Copy specs
gulp.src(['dest/**/*.spec.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/test'));

//Delete
del.sync(['dest/**/*.spec.js']);
```

Where 'dest' - is your destination output folder for js compiled files.

As a side not - I do not really follow why would you like to do that. By moving resulting js files you most likely will break imports if any between them and the rest of the application. For example if you have something like this in your spec.ts file:

```
import {F} from '../core/Commons';
```

it will not work after copying it into 'test' subdirectory as the path '../core/Commons' will become invalid.

Instead you should from the beginning have all your spec files in the 'test' folder and ts compiler will will do the job of puting js output to the 'test' directory in the destination folder.

Hope this will help.